# Is there anything I can do in xcode to resolve the this is not utf-8 static library issue?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

[image: Problem in the image]

I asked someone to make me a static library instead of providing me with a dynamic library and these are the errors produced after I both drag and drop the file into a new empty project and when I import the file like so: `#import "ftrapi.a"`.

Is there anything I do from my end to resolve these issues

Does this have anything to do with architecture or does this have to do with xcode settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't import a static library, you link it.  i.e. if you have somewhere

```
#import "ftrapi.a"
```

this is wrong, it's an object code library, not a header file.  Remove all such statements and in the Build Phases tab of your project, add the library to the "Link Binary with libraries" section.

You will also need a header file that you *do* import into your code.  Get the person who built the library to send you the public header(s).